# How to close channel when there is unknown number of inputs to it?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

API : https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/articles?page=1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

type ArticleResponse struct {
    Page       int `json:"page"`
    PerPage    int `json:"per_page"`
    Total      int `json:"total"`
    TotalPages int `json:"total_pages"`
    Data []Article `json:"data"`
}

type Article struct {
    Title       string      `json:"title"`
    URL         string      `json:"url"`
    Author      string      `json:"author"`
    NumComments int         `json:"num_comments"`
    StoryID     int32 `json:"story_id"`
    StoryTitle  string `json:"story_title"`
    StoryURL    string `json:"story_url"`
    ParentID    int32 `json:"parent_id"`
    CreatedAt   int         `json:"created_at"`
}

type CommentTitle struct{
    NumberOfComments int `json:"number_of_comments"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Page int `json:"from_page"`
}

const (
    GET_HOST_URL = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/"
    PATH = "api/articles"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main(){
    comment_title_chan := make(chan CommentTitle)
    var commentTitleSlice []CommentTitle
    
    // pilot call to get total number of pages
    totalPage := makePaginatedRequest(1, comment_title_chan, true)

    // making concurrent requests to multiple pages at once
    for j:=1;j<=totalPage;j++{
        go makePaginatedRequest(j, comment_title_chan, false)
    }
    for j:=0; j<20;j++ {
        commentTitleSlice = append(commentTitleSlice, <-comment_title_chan)
    }
    
    for _,article := range commentTitleSlice{
        fmt.Println(article.NumberOfComments, "\t\t", article.Title)
    }
}

func makePaginatedRequest(pageNo int, chunk chan CommentTitle, pilotMode bool) int{
    uri := GET_HOST_URL + PATH
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", uri, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    q := req.URL.Query()
    q.Add("page", strconv.Itoa(pageNo))
    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error on response.\n[ERROR] -", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    var articleResponse ArticleResponse
    if err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&articleResponse) ; err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    if !pilotMode{
        for _, article := range articleResponse.Data{
            if(article.Title != "" && article.NumComments != 0){
                ct := CommentTitle{article.NumComments, article.Title, pageNo}
                wg.Add(1)
                chunk <- ct
                wg.Done()
            }
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
    return articleResponse.TotalPages
}
```

Problem statement:

There is one api which gives data when passed page number in query params. I am expected to make a call all pages and fetch all articles with valid titles and number of comments field.

Solution:

step-1: I first make a pilot call to api to get to know number of pages as it is a part of response json.

step-2: I spin up multiple goroutines(number of goroutines = total number of pages)

step-3: each goroutine will make a call to corresponding page and fetches data and sends it to data channel.

step-4: data received in channel is appended to a slice , slice is used for further computation(sorting based on number of comments of an article)

Problem:
I am not aware out of total number of records - how many are valid, Hence I dont know when to close the channel from sender (Multiple sender and single receiver in my scenario).

I tried using one more additional signal channel, but again when will I know all goroutines have completed their job so that i can send a signal for further computation ?

I have even used WaitGroup, but this is at a individual goroutine level - still i will not be able to know when all goroutines have completed theit job.

One more similar question in SO didn't help much : [Closing channel of unknown length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283255/closing-channel-of-unknown-length)

Update : In the code I have hardcoded j loop value to 20 - that is exactly where I am facing issue. I dont know till where to loop, If i increase it to more then 50, received is blocked.

Comment: Update : In the code I have hardcoded j loop value to 20 - that is exactly where I am facing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the waitgroup incorrectly.

Add to the waitgroup when you create a goroutine, and wait for everything to complete in a separate goroutine, then close the channel:

```
for j:=1;j<=totalPage;j++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go makePaginatedRequest(j, comment_title_chan, false)
}
go func() {
  wg.Wait()
  close(comment_title_chan)
}()
```

Mark it completed when goroutine returns:

```
func makePaginatedRequest(pageNo int, chunk chan CommentTitle, pilotMode bool) int{
  defer wg.Done()
  ...
```

Comment: I concur. In a more serious solution I'd go with a `sync/atomic` counter so that each goroutine would atomically decrement it by 1 after completing its job, and whichever were to find it had decremented the counter to zero, would close the channel. But I'd still recommend the existing solution—fixed as explained in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But I get one more error after imlementing your suggestion: panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter

Comment: You have to remove your existing waitgroup code.

Comment: yes, I removed existing waitgroup, this is code with your suggestions: https://play.golang.org/p/DxZBtraN2JD
(plz dont try in playground, copy to local and run)

Comment: Got it, `defer wg.Done() ` should be inside `if !pilotMode{..}` block, Thanks, this works, unblocking with another goroutine was the thing i had to think of. Thanks!